# How to copy and edit XML file in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm copying the contents of an XML file into another XML file, on which this is the last line:

```
</references></resume></xpath>
```

I should only write upto `</resume>`, not `</xpath>`.
How to achieve that in Perl? Can I use a regular expression?

This is the command that I use to print the output:

```
$out_content .= "$_";
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are assembling pieces of XML into a larger one by string concatenation. Don't do it, it is error-prone. Instead, rely on a real XML toolkit that understands the complexity involved.

For example, XML::Twig comes with the tools [xml_split](http://p3rl.org/xml_split) and [xml_merge](http://p3rl.org/xml_merge) that easily do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 ways to do it:

- Bad but fast way: use regex

---

```
 $outContent = $contentOfOldXmlFile;
 $outContent =~ s#^.*<xpath>((.|\n)*)</xpath>$#$1#;
```

- Correct way: use `XML::DOM` library

---

```
use XML::DOM;
use XML::XQL; 
use XML::XQL::DOM; 

eval {
  my $xml=new XML::DOM::Parser->parsefile($yourFilename);
  my $outContent = "";
  for($xml->xql(qq(//resume))) {
    $outContent .= $_->toString();
  }
  $xml->dispose();
};
print "ERROR:$@\n" if $@;
```

---

And then you have the new content into `$outContent` that you can print or write to the file you want.

Preferably use the `XML::DOM` API to have the content you want  ( with `$node->toString()` )instead of concatenating pieces of strings.